# Character mapping issue .NET-Informix

Tags: .net, informix, windows-server-2003

I'm having a very strange issue when I retrieve the data from the DB in the server gets misread. 
The original message is: 
`Avería resuelta Le comunicamos que la avería registrada en la dirección #DIRECCION# ha sido cerrada #FECHAHORAFIN#.`

And the message we get on the server is this:
`Aver¡a resuelta Le comunicamos que la aver¡a registrada en la direcci¢n #DIRECCION# ha sido cerrada #FECHAHORAFIN#.`

We in the message we have special latin-1 characters, and we are specifiying in the connection string the charset as follows `db_locale=es_es.cp1252; client_locale=es_es.cp1252`

And the strange thing is that when I execute the (console) application from mi local machine it gets executed just fine, but when I execute it from the server it doesn't recognize the characters good.

The server is a Windows Server 2003 and my local machine is Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The value that this query, `SELECT tabname, site FROM systables WHERE tabid IN ( 90, 91 );`is thowing, is the following:

`tabname      site 
  GL_COLLATE  es_ES.1252 
  GL_CTYPE    es_ES.1252`

Comment: What is the locale of your database? Can you post the result of the following query done on your database? `SELECT tabname, site FROM systables WHERE tabid IN ( 90, 91 );` .

Comment: Question answered in main question. Thank you for the helping hand @Luis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to localize the aplication with the current culture setting

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
```